# I get blank value when i print user outside find method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

To get data from MongoDB

```
var user;
model.findOne({},(err,users)=>{
  user=users;
  console.log(user); does not print blank
 });
console.log(user);  // prints blank
```

Comment: look for promises in nodejs then you'll understand the async nature of nodejs.

Comment: I do not see any query in findOne.

Answer (score 0):

model.findOne is a asynchronous function. That means that console.log(user) (prints blank) may execute before model.findOne.

Answer (score 0):

Here what you can do is

```
var user;
(async function(){
   await model.findOne({},(err,users)=>{
      user=users;
      console.log(user);
     });
    console.log(user);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of Asynch processing that NodeJS follows .So what happens in this  when we have code like say

```
setTimeout(()=>{
console.log("Here")
},0);
console.log("Outside Timeout");
```

In this example the timeout is 0 ms but still the "Outside Timeout" gets prints before "Here"

So output is :

```
Outside Timeout
Here
```

Similar thing is happening with your code . Well  this is all based on the Node JS internal structure having call stack , Node API , callBack Queue and Event Loop.

So try to understand the internal structure of node js and it will be fine for you to get hold of it

But to make your code work use promises or Async-await .It will work as you expect it to work